# SQLAlchemy: Possible to declare a column as primary key declaratively?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a base class mixin:

```
class MyColumns(object):
    id = Column(Integer)
    foo = Column(Integer)
    bar = Column(Integer)

class MyMainTable(MyColumns, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'main_table'
    pk_id = PrimaryKeyConstraint("id")
```

I want to be able to declare `id` as the PK on MyMainTable. I can't declare it as PK within `MyColumns`, because I need to use `MyColumns` in another table, where id is NOT the PK (done for auditing purposes). When I run the above code, I get

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|MyMainTable|main_table could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'main_table'
```

Is there any way to add the PK declaration this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution as documented here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/constraints.html#setting-up-constraints-when-using-the-declarative-orm-extension

You need to add the constraints to `__table_args__`:

```
class MyColumns(object):
    id = Column(Integer)
    foo = Column(Integer)
    bar = Column(Integer)

class MyMainTable(MyColumns, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'main_table'
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", name="pk_id"),
    )
```

Comment: Your answer helped me: thanks! A quick addition: `PrimaryKeyConstraint` is, as of SQLA 1.0, imported from `sqlalchemy.schema`.